# Unable to render user object to EJS view header.ejs

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, ejs

I am new to EJS and Node.js. I have been struggling to send the user object data to ejs template page. Actually, I want to  display the current user's name who logged into the portal.

This is some portion of **app.js**

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.success_msg=req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg=req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.not_registered_user_msg=req.flash('not_registered_user_msg');
  res.locals.authdata = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  next();
});
//Get user info
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
  if(firebase.auth().currentUser!=null){
      var id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      var profileRef = fbRef.child('users');
      var query = profileRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(id);
      query.once('value', function(snap){
      var user = JSON.stringify(snap.val());
      console.log('User data is: '+user);
      res.locals.user = user;
     });
   }
  next();
 });
```

Here is the **header.ejs** where I want to retrieve and display current user's name:
[image]

I am able to enter into the if condition., and able to print the phrase "**Welcome,**". But unable to get the actual user data, it simply showing empty space like this
[image]

please suggest me, where did i gone wrong here! Thanks in advance.
As per sugegstion i am adding logs from console here. I am getting user data from firebase including child id as marked here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
var user = JSON.stringify(snap.val());
console.log('User data is: '+user);
res.locals.user = user;
```

You're converting the `user` object into a JSON string. Try this instead:

```
var user = snap.val();
console.log('User data is: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
res.locals.user = user;
```

I'm not really familiar with Firebase but I'd also guess that `once` is asynchronous, so you'd need to wait before calling `next`, a bit like this:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) {
    // ... This bit the same as before ...

    query.once('value', function(snap) {
        var user = snap.val();
        console.log('User data is: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
        res.locals.user = user;
        next();
    });
}
else {
    next();
}
```

If that still doesn't work, could you include the output of the console logging in your question?

Comment: ,I tried this suggestion! But no luck. I got the userdata from firebase successfully as before. But , unable to send it properly to view page. Not sure whats gone wrong here.I have added console logs as per your sugegstion. Have a look.

Comment: @Mahesh Your `first_name` and `last_name` are in a nested object, under a key called `-Ktiv6...`. I don't know what the significance of that key is but you'll need to grab that inner object as your `user` rather than just passing it on as is.

Comment: ah! Got you skirtle. Even i am suspecting that. I will try it.Great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From reading over the express documentation, it seems that the arguments passed into the request handler are `req` and `res`.

You do not get the `next` function as an argument. With that said, you need to change your `app.get` to an `app.use` which is where you get the actual `next` function.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    const { uid } = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const profileRef = fbRef.child('users')
    const query = profileRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid);
    query.once('value', snap => {
      const user = JSON.stringify(snap.val())
      res.locals.user = user
    })
  }
  next()
 })
```

Comment: The three arguments, `req`, `res` and `next` are the standard arguments for (almost) all Express handlers, including both `use` and `get`. It is sometimes referred to as the 'middleware interface'. You may be right that `use` would be a better choice for handling authentication but if the OP wanted to restrict it to only GET requests then using `get` would make sense.

Comment: @Francisco Mateo , Tried this.No improvement. I have added consle logs. Please have a look.

Comment: @skirtle was not aware of that. Thanks!